# How do I use a UUID in a JDBC template?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jdbc, jdbctemplate

I'm using the spring framework with the JDBC template and I'm also using postgres.

I have tables in postgres that use UUIDs as the primary key and the type of that column is postgres' [native UUIDs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-uuid.html). How do I store these UUIDs in a prepared statement created through the JDBC template?

I've tried converting the UUID to a string like so:

```
int rowsAffected = this.jdbc.update(sql, new Object[] {
    baseMaterial.getId().toString().toLowerCase(),
    baseMaterial.getName(),
    baseMaterial.getDescription()
});
```

but that results in this error:

```
ERROR: column "id" is of type uuid but expression is of type character varying
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

And if I just use the raw UUID like so:

```
int rowsAffected = this.jdbc.update(sql, new Object[] {
    baseMaterial.getId(),
    baseMaterial.getName(),
    baseMaterial.getDescription()
});
```

then I end up with this error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Can't infer the SQL type to use for an instance of java.util.UUID. Use setObject() with an explicit Types value to specify the type to use.
```

Any ideas? This is driving me mad.

Comment: Which version of the PostgreSQL JDBC driver are you using?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel `<version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>`

Comment: I recommend you update to 42.1.4 and see if that fixes your problem, 9.1-901 is 6 years old.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel and sure enough, that fixed it. post that as an answer and i'll accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The PostgreSQL driver version you are using is 6 years old, and a lot has been changed/improved since. I advise to upgrade to version 42.1.4.

I have scanned the [release notes](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/changelog.html), but I haven't found the specific version they added (or improved) support for UUID.

Answer (score 2):

Try using Types in your query like this :

```
int[] types = {Types.VARCHAR, Types.VARCHAR, Types.VARCHAR};

int rowsAffected = this.jdbc.update(sql, new Object[]{
    baseMaterial.getId().toString().toLowerCase(),
    baseMaterial.getName(),
    baseMaterial.getDescription()
}, types);//<<-----------specify the type of each attribute
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try using Prepared Statement and let the DB handle the uuid creation using a function uuid_generate_v1()

In order to use this function you first need to create an extension by running this in your Postgres DB:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";
```

And then in your DAO you can for instance:

```
private String ADD_USER = "insert into Users(id, name, description) values (uuid_generate_v1(), ?, ?)";
    
jdbcTemplate.update(ADD_USER, new PreparedStatementSetter() {
    @Override
    public void setValues(PreparedStatement preparedStatement) throws SQLException {
        preparedStatement.setString(1, name);
        preparedStatement.setString(2, description);
    }
});
```

You won't need to worry about inserting the uuid since the DB will do that for you using the function uuid_generate_v1();